# Using a variable inside the Math.random function

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

I am working on a piece of code which make an array full of numbers with the amount of numbers i want, but instead of this beeing static with 16 numbers i tried to change 16 to a variable but the math.floor/randome cant read it it only spits out Not a number wierdly enough.

EDIT: with 16 put in it works, but i cant use a variable (declared in the same function ofc)after i console.log the variable it shows it as a number but then my browser freezes

Is There anyone who knows how to change this

```
while(arr.length < pictures.length) {
    var randomenumber = Math.floor((Math.random()* 16));
    if(arr.indexOf(randomenumber) > -1) {
        continue;
    }
    arr[arr.length] = randomenumber;
}

//cheat sheet
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
    document.write(arr[i]);
    document.write("<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issues if you use `var length = 16` and `Math.floor((Math.random() * length))`.

**Working snippet**:

```js
var arr = [], length = 16;

while(arr.length < length) {
    var randomenumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * length));
    if(arr.indexOf(randomenumber) > -1) {
        continue;
    }
    arr[arr.length] = randomenumber;
}

//cheat sheet
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
    document.write(arr[i]);
    document.write("<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse it in `integer` using `parseInt`.

```
var num = 16;
var randomenumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * parseInt(num)));
```